# Investing in DHA property in Queensland

Tags: investing, australia, rental-property, rate-of-return

I was interested in investing in DHA (Defence Housing Australia) properties in Queensland. Does anyone who may have any DHA investment properties within Queensland know how these properties have performed in terms of rental and capital returns over the last 5 years?

What are some of the criteria (benefits and pitfalls) I should be considering before purchasing such an investment property from DHA?